# How to calculate timestamp difference in mongodb (in hours)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here's my data:

```
[
   {
       id: 1, 
       starttime: ISODate("2015-08-24T00:00:00.000Z"), 
       endtime: ISODate("2015-08-24T07:00:00.000Z")
   },
   {
       id: 2, 
       starttime: ISODate("2015-08-24T20:00:00.000Z"), 
       endtime: ISODate("2015-08-25T01:00:00.000Z")
   }
]
```

can I make a mongodb query to display duration (or in this case a difference operation) of starttime and endtime with results like:

```
[ {id:1, duration: 7}, {id: 2, duration: 5}]
```

Notice that timestamp can have different date so `$hour`(aggregation pipeline) might not work. Can anyone help ? Thank you

Comment: You can use a projection with $substract : {$project: {_id:'$id', duration : {$subtract : ['$endtime', '$starttime']}}},

Comment: Tried that, result: [{id:1, duration: null}, {id: 2, duration: null}]

Comment: Sorry, I have incorrect variable name, $subtract works, here's the result: [{id: 1, duration:25200000}, {id:2, duration:18000000}]. is this in seconds?

Comment: It is in milliseconds

Comment: duration: {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$endtime", "$starttime"]}, 3600000]}, Thank you!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
db.collectionname.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      duration: {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$endtime", "$starttime"]}, 3600000]}
  }}
])
```

Comment: [Difference in milliseconds](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/#subtract-two-dates)

Comment: 1 Hour = 3600000 Milliseconds

Answer (score 7):

Starting in `Mongo 5.0`, the [`$dateDiff`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/#mongodb-expression-exp.-dateDiff) aggregation operator perfectly fits your use case of producing the difference between two dates:

```
// { _id: 1, start: ISODate("2015-08-24T00:00:00Z"), end: ISODate("2015-08-24T07:00:00Z") }
// { _id: 2, start: ISODate("2015-08-24T20:00:00Z"), end: ISODate("2015-08-25T01:00:00Z") }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project:
    { duration:
      { $dateDiff: { startDate: "$start", endDate: "$end", unit: "hour" } }
    }
  }
])
// { "_id" : 1, "duration" : 7 }
// { "_id" : 2, "duration" : 5 }
```

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me.

```
const start_time = "2021-08-10T16:25:46.191Z",
 end_time = "2021-08-10T20:25:46.191Z"

const total = new Date(end_time).getTime() -  new Date(start_time).getTime();
  const hours = (Math.floor((total)/1000))/3600;
console.log(hours);
```

Comment: The question is about MongoDB specifically, not JavaScript in general.