# mongodb calculate difference between two attributes of object field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a mongodb collection say `customer` and I have saved the status changes in a `status_changes` as object which has keys with status and value with status change date like below:

```
Name    |        Status changes      |
--------------------------------------
Anil    | { "lead" : ISODate("2018-01-22T06:07:30.707Z"), "verification" : ISODate("2018-01-22T06:08:45.919Z"), "active" : ISODate("2018-01-22T06:11:24.468Z")}
---------------------------------------
Sudhir  | { "lead" : ISODate("2017-08-20T06:07:30.707Z"), "verification" : ISODate("2017-08-22T06:08:45.919Z")}
```

How do I get the average time between the status changes of all customer in the below format considering that there could be in total 3 statuses(`lead`, `verification`, `active`) and the status changes can only proceed in one direction i.e. `lead`->`verification`->`active`?

Please notice that my question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138877/how-to-calculate-timestamp-difference-in-mongodb-in-hours) since the dates are part of the same object field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate timestamp difference in mongodb (in hours)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138877/how-to-calculate-timestamp-difference-in-mongodb-in-hours)

Comment: I looked at the above question before posting. The data structure is different in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this, this will return transition time in mills, we can convert this to minute or hour

```
db.col.aggregate(
    [
        {$project : {
            leadToVerification : { $subtract : ["$status.verification" , "$status.lead"] },
            verificationToActive : { $subtract : ["$status.active" , "$status.verification"] }
            }
        },
        {$group : {_id : null, leadToVerification : {$avg : "$leadToVerification"}, verificationToActive : {$avg : "$verificationToActive"}}}
    ]
)
```

output

```
{ "_id" : null, "leadToVerification" : 86475212, "verificationToActive" : 158549 }
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks @Saravana